# Error connecting MySQL to ColdFusion10

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I can't get my ColdFusion 10 datasource to connect to MySql v5.xx

For the connector type, I'm using: MySQL (4/5)

I get this error:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: cfMySqlDSN
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
The root cause was that: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
```

Could anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: show the DSN. Could be something like trying to use TCP connections and MySQL hasn't been configured to allow them, or a firewall silently dropping packets to/from port 3306, etc... impossible to say from what you've posted.

Comment: MySQL server is up and running, also I check my testConnection too in MySQL workbench...

Other values in CFIDE/admin are as follows - 
CF Data Source Name: cfMySqlDSN
Database: mysqldb (this is what I created in MySQL)
Server: 127.0.0.1 (I tried localhost too)
Port: 3306 (Default one)
Username: root
password:

Comment: doesn't mean much. workbench can be connecting using local unix-domain sockets, while CF is trying to use TCP.

Comment: Marc B,

I appreciate the quick response. Anyway I could resolve this issue.

Comment: like I said, show the DSN (and what ever other connection/related stuff you think might be relevant). we can't help you other than guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same thing, raised it with Adobe, and no-one could replicate it.

In the end I rolled back to the version of the MySQL driver that shipped with CF9, and it worked.  Possibly try that.

The file in question is `[ColdFusion dir]/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/mysql-connector-java-commercial-[some version number]-bin.jar`